# Magento 2: Show disabled subcategory products in parent category

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category, category-products

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 and I have an anchor parent category that has some disabled subcategories. When I disabled these subcategories, all the subcategory products are not showing in the parent category page, but if i enable it, it will show just fine. I need the subcategories to be disabled, but the products still showing in parent category page.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Side note: I see that the products are still searchable and available when the subcategory is disabled, but the products are not showing in the parent category.

Comment: Hey if you are disabling the subcategory then i think product won't show up so if you want to see those product in your parent category then you have to assign those product to parent category then run indexing it will show up.

Comment: @ShubhamKhandelwal We will eventually turn on the subcategory so we don´t want to move the products to the parent to then have to move them again. (btw this is done through an integration so we would need to change the PIM which we would prefer not to)

Comment: yes if you enable subcategory then you don't need to assign product to parent but if you disable it then you have to do such kind of thing. Hope now everything working fine as expected.